# What is the correct Hashing by division formula?

Tags: algorithm, formula

I was looking at this wikipedia page.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Hashing_by_division

It says that the formula/scheme for Hashing by division is `h(x) = M mod m`.

[image]

Is this correct or am I missing something?

The source book that is mentioned seems to contain `h(x) = x mod m` which seems align with what I've seen on the internet more of.

Could this be the case of intentional incorrect information? What is the correct hashing by division formula?

Comment: The current text is the result of a localized rewrite, try the [version before it](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hash_table&oldid=1085561450). It does seem slightly more sensible. (obtained by searching WikiBlame for "hash digest")

Comment: [NIST](https://csrc.nist.gov/glossary/term/hash_digest) defines *hash digest* to be "The result of applying a hash function to data." The Wikipedia definition would therefore seem to be saying that the division formula hash function is a function of some first stage hash function modded by m. Perhaps having a first stage hash might improve uniformity of the outcomes, reducing the cost of collision resolutions?